# Is this closed subspace of Fréchet space complemented

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

In the hope of completing the rich tapestry of complemented (or not) topological vector subspaces, I would like to know (maybe it is immediate for specialists) 
whether the space of analytic functions is complemented  within the space of infinitely differentiable ones. I begin with the one-variable case

...  and make this precise.

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open subset. We consider
>   $$
> H(\Omega)=C^\omega(\Omega;\mathbb{C})\subset C^\infty(\Omega;\mathbb{C})
> $$
>   the large one being endowed with the standard topology defined by the seminorms
>   $$
> p_{\,n,B}=sup_{\ 0\leq |\alpha|\leq n\atop t\in B}|D^\alpha(f)[t]|\ . 
> $$
>   where $n\in \mathbb{N}, \alpha\in \mathbb{N}^2$, $B$ is a relatively compact open subset of $\Omega$ and the bi-indexed derivative is 
>   $$
> D^\alpha:=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^{\alpha[1]}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})^{\alpha[2]}\ .
> $$ 
>   I know that the subspace $H(\Omega)=C^\omega(\Omega;\mathbb{C})$ is complete and then closed for this (standard) topology. My question is the following
>
> Q) Is there a known closed complement of it i.e. a decomposition
>   $$
> C^\infty(\Omega;\mathbb{C})=C^\omega(\Omega;\mathbb{C})\oplus W=H(\Omega)\oplus W
> $$
>   where $W$ is closed ? (maybe the projector is an integro-differential operator ?) at least for some particular domains $\Omega$ ?

**Remark** i) This question is a reformulation of 
[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361195/complement-of-the-space-of-analytic-functions)
in MSE where it did not receive a complete answer.

ii) With the given topology, $C^\infty(\Omega;\mathbb{C})$ and $H(\Omega)=C^\omega(\Omega;\mathbb{C})$ are m-convex [Fréchet algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_algebra). Maybe (if possible) $W$ could have some algebraic structure (ideal ?).

Comment: To be precise, when you write $C^\omega(\Omega)$, do really mean the set of (real or complex?) valued *real analytic* functions (which is the usual convention) or do you mean the set of (complex valued) holomorphic functions, for which the usual notation would be $H(\Omega)$? If you mean the former, then there is no topological complement since the set is dense. And, if you really mean the usual topology of $C^\infty(\Omega)$, then $B\subset\Omega$ should be required to be relatively compact. Bounded generally gives a strictly stronger topology.

Comment: No, *it is not*. If e.g. $\Omega$ is the open unit disk, then $B=\Omega$ satisfies your requirement of being bounded open, and you get uniform convergence on $\Omega$ which is not the usual topology of $C^\infty(\Omega)$. I mean dense in your "large" space $C^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: O.K. thanks (I was thinking of $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$). Corrected !

Comment: [If you mean the former, then there is no topological complement since the set is dense.]---> No, I meant the complex valued (i.e. holomorphic) functions, I made the ranges precise in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$H(\Omega) $ is not complemented in $C^\infty (\Omega)$ e.g. for the unit disc in $\mathbb C $. This follows from the structure theory of Frechet spaces: The space of smooth functions is isomorphic to $s^\mathbb N$ and has a certain property  (DN$_{loc}$) of Vogt. If $H (\Omega) $ were complemented it would also have this property and hence   even property (DN) because it has continuous norms.  But this is not true for power series spaces of finite type.

I don't have any literature at hand.  The book of Meise and Vogt is a good starting point. The local condition is in a more recent article of Vogt.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, which "recent article of Vogt"?

Comment: Splitting of exact sequences of Fréchet spaces
in the absence of continuous norms from 2004.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth [The space of smooth functions is isomorphic to $s^\mathbb N$]---> Sorry, but what is $s$ ?

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for your answer (+1), I must digest it together with the reference you gave.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Well ... I feel sort of outsider. It seems, from the paper by P. Domanski and D. Vogt, that $s$ is the space of rapidly decreasing sequences.