# Exactness of injective tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, banach-spaces, tensor-products, tensor

For (algebraic) tensor products, it is well-known that the functor $A\otimes_R \cdot:Mod_R\rightarrow Mod_R$ is only (left-) exact when $A$ is a flat $R$-module.  In particular, all vector spaces are flat.  What happens in the continuous (archimedean) setting?:

Let $B$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space and suppose that $
f:E\rightarrow F,
$
is a continuous linear injective map from a separable nuclear space $E$ to a separable Banach space $F$, both infinite-dimensional (if it matters).  Let $\otimes_{\epsilon}$ denote the [injective tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_tensor_product) of LCS and let $\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}$ denote its completion.

Is the map
$
1_{B}\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} f: B\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} E \rightarrow B\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} F,
$
a continuous linear 1-1 map also?

*Related:*
This post is related to this [unanswered post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86330/exactness-of-completed-tensor-product-of-nuclear-spaces).

Comment: Do you mean just the injective tensor product or the completed injective tensor product?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth  (I made the correction) but indeed I'm interested in the completed injective tensor product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always true (without nuclearity): If $T_j:E_j\to F_j$ are continuous linear maps between Hausdorff locally convex spaces and $E_2$ is complete then $$ T_1\hat\otimes_\varepsilon T_2: E_1 \hat\otimes_\varepsilon E_2 \to F_1\hat\otimes_\varepsilon F_2$$ is injective if so are $T_1$ and $T_2$. This is 16.2.2 in Jarchows's book *Locally Convex Spaces*.

Comment: Thank you very much Jochen.  Out of curiousity I'm assuming the result fails if the completion is not taken?

Comment: No,  without the completions it is much easier.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that I really enjoyed your book "Derived Functors in Functional Analysis" :)  I had read it during my PhD some years ago

Comment: Thank you......