# Image of a complete topological group under open and surjective map is complete?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

A uniform space $X$ is complete if every Cauchy filter in $X$ is convergent. Here we do not require $X$ to be Hausdorff.

**Question.**

Let $G$ be a complete topological group and let $H$ be a topological group. Suppose that $q:G\twoheadrightarrow H$ is an open and surjective homomorphism of topological groups.

Is $H$ complete topological group?

**Motivation.**

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $q:X\twoheadrightarrow X/Y$ be the quotient with respect to some linear subspace $Y \subseteq X$. Then $q$ is open and surjective.  Actually every open surjective linear map with domain $X$ is of this form. It is standard result in functional analysis that if $X$ is Banach, then $X/Y$ is a seminormed and complete space (if $Y$ is closed, then $X/Y$ is a Banach space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. This is already false for topological vector spaces, since every (Hausdorff) topological vector space arises as the quotient of a complete one, see Jochen Wengenroth's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57654/example-of-noncomplete-quotient-of-complete-lcs-mod-closed-subspace); see also the [original article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01154284) by Susanne Dierolf.